# Bash: Ignore SIGNT (ctrl-c) x amount of times

Tags: bash, bash-trap

So, in this program, using BASH, I am trying to ignore or trap <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> multiple times (not infinite) before it takes.

at the moment I know how to ignore the command once.
But I have no idea how to increment or decrement the amount of times it is ignored.

CODE:

```
#! /bin/bash
trap 'justonce' 2
justonce()
{
    echo "you sure?"
 trap 2
}
while true; do
    echo -n "."
        sleep 1
done
```

Thank you

Comment: David, if you are happy with this answer, please mark it as "accepted"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop and a variable:

```
#! /bin/bash
ignore=4
trap 'justonce' 2
justonce()
{
    echo "you sure? $ignore left"
    if [ $((ignore)) -eq 0 ]
    then
        exit 1
    fi
    ignore=$((ignore-1))
}
while true; do
    echo -n "."
    sleep 1
done
```